# How to convert input data frame columns to vectors

Tags: r

I have written several functions and want to only apply them to the last two columns of an input CSV file. The question is how to convert the last two columns to vectors and apply my functions to them?

```
myAvg <- function(anyVector){      
  average <- sum(anyVector) / length(anyVector)
  return(average)
}

mySD <- function(anyVector){        
    std_Dev <- sqrt(sum((anyVector - mean(anyVector)) ^ 2 / (length(anyVector) - 1)))
  return(std_Dev)
  }


myRange <- function(anyVector){        
    myRange <- max(anyVector) - min(anyVector)
  return(myRange)
  }  

data <- read.csv("CardioGoodnessFit.csv")
 print(data)
```

[image: Here is the first couple lines of the file]

Comment: please include the data as text

Comment: This is not a range `myRange<-max(anyVector)-min(anyVector)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mako212 suggested this can be simple achieved by using the `apply` function in R:

```
avg = apply(data[,c('Income','Miles')],MARGIN=2,FUN=myAvg)
sdev = apply(data[,c('Income','Miles')],MARGIN=2,FUN=mySD)
```

Function `myAvg` will be `apply`ied to each column of the subset of data. Columns of interest can be specified either by providing the names of the columns or column numbers in a vector. `Apply` is generally used for a matrix or data.frame type object. While `MARGIN` provides the option to apply the `FUN` column-wise (`MARGIN = 2`) , row-wise (`MARGIN=1`) or both(to each element of data `MARGIN=c(1,2)`)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to convert to vectors (or in this case, even to write functions) if you use *e.g.* `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
# means
data %>% summarise(avg = mean(Income))
data %>% summarise(avg = mean(Miles))

# standard deviations
data %>% summarise(sdev = sd(Income))
data %>% summarise(sdev = sd(Miles))

# range
data %>% summarise(range = max(Income) - min(Income))
data %>% summarise(range = max(Miles) - min(Miles))
```